# How to fix all my images being render black?

Tags: blender

All my images are rendering black. The output of my animation is a `.mpg` video. The images themselves were created in GIMP and saved as non-transparent `.png`'s.

Can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: OK, I've got my image to show up by adding a light source, but the white background isn't white - it's gray... Anyone know how to fix this? If I make the sunlight intensity too high, the image can't be seen; however, if I make the image sunlight too low, the background goes all gray...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you go to the properties menu (Shift-F7), and then click on the materials tab, there you should check the 'shadeless' box.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the properties menu (SHIFT + F7) and change the **emit value** under the ***shading category*** to a value between **0** and **1**.

Then gradually change this emit value to return the expected shading of the object. To do so you have to render the view several times.

This means you can also retain the realistic 3D nature of the object.